# Is realloc in C linear?

Tags: c, memory-management, time-complexity, realloc

A Java `ArrayList` is O(n) if you're adding to the beginning, because `System.arraycopy()` is linear.
When making an ArrayList in C, i'd use `realloc` to reallocate the array when it gets full. Is `realloc` linear?

`ArrayList` in java is basically just a dynamic array. `System.arraycopy` is linear. That's what I know exactly. I think that it copies the input array into the output array element by element.

Linear time complexity: The time it takes to complete a task is proportional to the amount of inputs. So copying an array element by element is linear, because it takes longer to finish the bigger the array.

Comment: Not sure about Java. But realloc may get new memory area if the existing one is insufficient.

Comment: And when it gets the new memory area, is it O(n)?

Comment: What is `n`? The size you pass to `realloc`?

Comment: This depends on the memory organization of the heap. I believe the standard realloc method uses the best fit method which would make this Θ(k) where k is the number of memory blocks.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The memory chunk that gets passed to realloc

Comment: realloc will return the same pointer if it was able to allocate new space to the end. In this case, the complexity is only the time spent allocating the new pages. However in the worst case, it needs to copy everything over into a new position in memory and will return a new pointer.

Comment: The C standard does not specify the time complexity of `realloc` or `malloc`. When `realloc` must move data, the complexity is necessarily at least O(n) and is not more in a reasonable implementation except for effects caused by memory management such as swapping to disk. However, `malloc` and `realloc` must also manage internal data structures and may be subject to various possibly unpredictable delays depending on the implementation. Incidentally, do you have documentation saying Java’s `ArrayList` is O(n), or is that a supposition people spread around without authority?

Comment: "So copying an array element by element is linear, because it takes longer to finish the bigger the array." is an unwarranted assumption.  Select systems can re-map (copy) in less than O(n) time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've read that "System.arraycopy is O(n)" in Allen Downey's Think Data Structures

Comment: Which Compiler?  It could be different.

Comment: @Rick James gcc or clang